# Compiling Options in Code Blocks

Tags: c, compiler-construction, codeblocks

I want to to be able to enter the options in Code Blocks. Like I want to do `gcc -P test.c`. How should I go about doing this? Basically, I want Code Blocks to give a `prompt box` each time I compile so that I can enter the options in that box. Is that functionality available in Code Blocks?

Comment: Not sure what you want to read as answer, other than "click on the _settings_ menu, and select _compiler_". Does that not work for you?

Comment: No @Damon, this does not work. I have edited the question. Check it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour that you want in your updated answer is not available in Code::Blocks.

However, you should be able to get this behaviour if you invest the time to write a plugin for that (should be under an hour, depening on your wxWidgets skill, the GUI bit to pop up the dialog will probably be the hardest thing).

Either write a script plugin (this is allegedly the easiest and quickest way, though I've never done that, so cannot tell for sure) -- look at `share/codeblocks/scripts/sample_plugin.script`, and see if you can adapt that -- or write a proper plugin in C++.
Edit: [some sparse docs on script plugin](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Script_plugins).

Look for example at `src/plugins/autosave/autosave.[h|cpp]` (which is one of the most primitive plugins) to learn how this is done. Something like this should work:

- Derive a class from `cbPlugin`, implement all the pure virtuals as `{}` (don't need them)
- Put a `namespace { PluginRegistrant<YourClassName> reg(_T("Readable Plugin Name")); }` into your source file
- Register for `EVT_COMMAND(cbEVT_COMPILER_STARTED...)` inside your `BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE/END_EVENT_TABLE` block.
- In your event handler, pop up the dialog, read out the textbox, and modify any settings you want. Either modify the compiler's settings, or use the pointer to the project contained in the the event, which lets you access project settings and targets with their own settings
- You probably want to undo your changes, too. So do the same for `cbEVT_COMPILER_FINISHED`, restoring the original settings

Alternatively, one could probably just call `cbProject::ShowOptions()` (after all, the event gives you a pointer to a `cbProject`, so why not just use that) when `cbEVT_COMPILER_STARTED` is received, that should bring up the builtin options dialog.